# Is there Any Standard Framework for php?

Tags: php, frameworks

There are many PHP Frameworks out there but i want to know is there a standard Objective framework with a great architecture similar J2SE or .NET Framework?

I see many similar questions like this but most of them are about beginners or special kind of programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the [list of stable php frameworks](http://phpframeworks.com), you can checkout and decide for yourself as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a special framework for an special requirement! I want a framework for almost any kind of web service or web sites.

Comment: @Jalal Amini: This is what the list suggests. Almost any of these can help you to create any web site.

Comment: The list hasn't been updated in a long time. A more up-to-date list is in [hotframeworks.com](http://hotframeworks.com)

Answer (score 1):

Zend seems to be the de facto PHP framework, given that PHP is now maintained by the Zend group. However, there are numerous open source alternatives that are excellent, including CakePHP and CodeIgniter.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far to call ZF the de-facto standard. It's definitely one of the major frameworks, but like you say, there is others with an equal spread. Btw Zend Framework is open source too.